# Cloudberry Backup API: Listing Plan Items

Tags: c#, powershell, cloudberry

I'm trying to list selected folder paths in all backup plans using the Cloud.Backup.API.dll and am not having much luck.  I've given up trying to load the dll in powershell (using Add-Type returns 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types') and am instead writing a simple console application in C#. So far I have:

```
foreach (BackupPlan plan in BackupProvider.GetBackupPlans())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(plan.PlanItems);
    }
```

However, PlanItems returns:

CloudBerryLab.Backup.API.BackupPlan+d__0

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C# this will list paths:

```
foreach (string _item in plan.PlanItems)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(_item);    
               }
```